# How do I output a variable from JavaScript to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI6cf.jpg)

1)Make up the design below

2)License type output in Bebas font-output via font-face

3)***Display the selected license type and total amount***

4)The format of the link in the Buy Now button is formed at your discretion

(How to execute an item highlighted in italics)

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events). Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. Please read [ask] and try something yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an HTML element (like a paragraph) where you want to display the amount.

If you give the element an `id` attribute with the value "my-paragraph", then your script can get the element like `myParagraph = document.getElementById("my-paragraph")`.

Then you can change the content of the element like `myParagraph.textContent = myAmount`.

Begin your learning journey on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction